# Upgrade Magento From 1.9.3.3 To 1.9.3.4

Tags: upgrade

How can u upgrade 1.9.3.3 To 1.9.3.4 through FTP. I am on shared hosting so i don't have ssh access.
Which are the fires and folder do i need to replace ?

Please Any one can give me a step by step procedure...

Thank you

Comment: Why don't you follow this blog https://magecomp.com/blog/how-to-upgrade-magento/

Answer (score 6):

**Step1:**
Take the backup of `downloader->.htaccess`
and rename it

**Step2:**
Go to root `pkginfo->delte Mage_All_Latest.txt`

**Step3:**
load `admin->downloader-:Magento conectmanager` and login

check for upgrades
next check all the Magento files except custom modules

**Step 4:** Click on commit changes

**Step 5:** It will take time next

**Step 6:** After completing delete the `maintanace.flag` in root folder

revert `downloader .htaccess`

remove cache and session.

**Step 7:** Check all your changes:

replace all you core files by meld if any:

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can upload all files of 1.9.3.4 through ftp.

- 1.9.3.4 package should not have local.xml file.
- When you will upload file, then it should just replace existing file or merge new file. It should not delete files

When all file will upload successfully, then open the URL in the browser. It will automatically update your database accordingly.

**Note: Please take database backup before doing above steps. If someone coded in core files that is not recommended, may be deleted/overwrite.**